# What is the security of XORing SHAKE256_XOF with itself?

Tags: random-number-generator, xor, keccak

After reading "[Can the xor of two RNG outputs ever be less secure than one of them?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/47446/can-the-xor-of-two-rng-outputs-ever-be-less-secure-than-one-of-them)" I wondered if you can increase security of [`SHAKE256_XOF`](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-185.pdf) by using another instance of the CSRNG.  The theoretical security of `SHAKE256_XOF` is 256 bits.  After a [theoretical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-3#Security_against_quantum_attacks) quantum attack it has `min(key_length/2, 256)` bit security. So using a 512 bit key `SHAKE256_XOF` should theoretically be able to generate a bit stream of any length with 256 bits of security against classical and quantum attacks.

If you were to compute `SHAKE256_XOF(key1) xor SHAKE256_XOF(key2)` where both keys are independent true random numbers of at least 512 bits:

1. Could you obtain a bit stream with more than 256 bits of security against classical attacks?
2. Could you obtain a bit stream with more than 256 bits of security against quantum attacks?
3. Can this lead to a bit stream that is weaker than 256 bits with the assumptions of the keys?
4. What it the security of N `SHAKE256_XOF` generators chained with `xor` for classical and quantum attacks?

Comment: "After a theoretical quantum attack it has `min(key_length/3, 256)` bit security." - no, it has `min(key_length/2, 256)` bit security - collision attacks do not apply, hence the best attack is straight Grover's.

Comment: @poncho: Wouldn't a birthday attack create the same bit stream with a successful collision effectively breaking it?

Comment: In a Birthday attack, we assume that the attacker can select *both* preimages (or, at least, influence them).  In your scenario (we compute SHAKE based on a secret key), the attacker cannot specify the key.